# adding two times, but result is 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add_two(h,m):

    try:
        att1 = datetime.strptime(h,"%H:%M %p")
        result = att1 + timedelta(minutes=int(m))   
        return result.strftime("%H:%M")
    except:
        return 0
```

Result is 0

Comment: Remove the try/except to see the actual error. Also, please add what's in `h` and `m`!

Comment: those are Dynamic values, when test case running it should be taken automatically, but in the arrags and att1 = ........()  missing some syntax

Comment: you generic `except` is hiding the informative error message!

Answer (score 0):

## try this update

```
import datetime

try:
    att1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(h,"%H:%M %p")
    result = att1 + datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(m))
    return result.strftime("%H:%M")
expect:
    return 0
```

Answer (score -1):

"try" doesn't actually do the function - it just confirms that it works.

Use an `else:` like so:

```py
else:
    att1 = datetime.strptime(h,"%H:%M %p")
    result = att1 + timedelta(minutes=int(m))
```

Comment: ...why? It seems to work perfectly well for me and has done in the past.

Comment: `try` doesn't just "confirm it works", it executes the full code block if no exception is encountered

Comment: hasn't been the case in my experience; i've used a try block, and when there was no error (with exception printing a state for debugging) my values weren't updated, so i had to redo them with else

Comment: evidently i'm wrong and will try to correct my answer

Comment: I can't comment on the above post yet, but timedelta() is undefined so unless he's defined it somewhere else it doesn't do anything.